# Xcode 4.4 error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.4

Since I updated Xcode to version 4.4, my project started to crash with the following error:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework.static', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

My project have an connection with a library, and i think that´s the error.

Any idea how to solve this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like something got corrupted during the update. Have you tried re-installing xCode yet? (Remove it completely and then do a clean install to be sure)

Comment: I am now trying that idea.... anyway if that didn t work Xcode 4.3 is downloading now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad... 
This error didn´t have anything directly related to the new release from apple, Xcode 4.4...

This app that i am working, is an enterprise app, so may people working at the same time.
And it needs this framework installed on Xcode : https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework.git.

So every time i update the Xcode i need to reinstall it..

Answer (score 1):

Try copying all your source code & classes somewhere, then create a new project, and paste back in all the code..

Could be a bit annoying but it will work.

At least, reinstall xCode.

Hope I was helpful to you.